# Last of neural network

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I wanna see the output of last layer before softmax unit in a neural network in tensorflow or keras how can this be done
I just want to see what features are learnt and what as are exact output values of each layer

Comment: would you mind posting your code...we can't guess otherwise

Comment: In tensorflow, you can just create an op which prints out, saves, or plots the logits (layer before softmax) in tensorboard, but without a code example we're limited in how much we can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
model.layers[idx].output
```

idx is the index of the layer and you can find it from `model.summary()`

e.g , to get the shape `model.layers[idx].output.get_shape()`